# How to read data from elastic search or opensearch using scroll api for java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to read data from elastic search or opensearch .
I want to use scroll api for this. I don't know how to use it. can someone answer me about it.

I required Java code for reading data from elastic search or opensearch

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:

> We no longer recommend using the scroll API for deep pagination. If
> you need to preserve the index state while paging through more than
> 10,000 hits, use the search_after parameter with a point in time
> (PIT).

If you need pagination I recommend you use "size" and "from" parameters.
For details and other solutions, you can check [this link.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html)

Here are some java examples for you.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-helpers.html

Comment: how you use this code in java.. do you have any integration code..